# Get elements from HashMap in Java?

Tags: java, hashmap, jsoup

I currently have the following code, which gets a table from a webpage, and put the elements into a HashMap (I think).

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(
            "http://www.sportinglife.com/greyhounds/abc-guide").get();

    Element tableHeader = doc.select("tbody").first();
    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
    for (Element element : tableHeader.children()) {
        // Here you can do something with each element
        if (element.text().indexOf("Pelaw Grange") > 0
                || element.text().indexOf("Shawfield") > 0
                || element.text().indexOf("Shelbourne Park") > 0
                || element.text().indexOf("Harolds Cross") > 0) {
            // do nothing
        } else {

            String dog = element.select("td:eq(0)").text();
            String race = element.select("td:eq(1)").text();
            data.put(dog, race);

        }
    }
    analyseRunners(data);
}
```

This seems to work OK and I now need it to run another method "analyseRunners", where it needs to go through each of the dogs and use that "dog" name to access another webpage where there is another table. Here's what I have so far...

```
String dogPage = "http://www.gbgb.org.uk/raceCard.aspx?dogName=" + dog;
    Document doc1 = Jsoup.connect(dogPage).get();

    int firsts = 0, seconds = 0, thirds = 0;


    Element tblHeader = doc1.select("tbody").first();
    for (Element element1 : tblHeader.children()){
        String position = element1.select("td:eq(4)").text();

        if (position.equals("1st")){
            firsts++;
        } else if (position.equals("2nd")){
            seconds++;
        } else if (position.equals("3rd")){
            thirds++;
        } else {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Firsts: " + firsts);
    System.out.println("Seconds: " + seconds);
    System.out.println("Thirds: " + thirds);
```

As you can see, I am trying to navigate to the webpage in jSoup using the "dog" from the first method above... this isn't working as it says "dog" cannot be resolved. How do I go about getting the dog name out of the HashMap and looping through every dog to work out how many 1st, 2nds and 3rds it has? (the fifth column on this page: http://www.gbgb.org.uk/raceCard.aspx?dogName=A%20Real%20Legend)

Comment: `for (String dog: data.keySet()) { // use the dog }`

Answer (score 0):

Use the dog names on your data map in a loop :

```
for(String dog : data.keySet())
{
    // use dog as required
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first iterate your map's key list and get the available dogs.
then process your logic inside that..

```js
for (String dog: data.keySet()) {

  String dogPage = "http://www.gbgb.org.uk/raceCard.aspx?dogName=" + dog;
  Document doc1 = Jsoup.connect(dogPage).get();
  ....................
}
```